# Ler arquivo XML com Argparse e converte-lo para JSON

Tags: python, json, xml

Olá! Tenho uma dúvida e sou bem novato no assunto: 
Preciso criar um código em Python que leia um arquivo **XML** e transforme esse mesmo arquivo em um **JSON**. Preciso utilizar o ***Argparse*** para isso, mas não estou restrito apenas a essa lib. Alguém consegue me dar essa luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está com sorte! Existe um módulo chamado `xmltodict` que faz exatamente isso:

```
import xmltodict, json
with open('arquivo.xml') as f:
    d = xmltodict.parse(f.read())
with open('arquivo.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f)
```

O módulo está [aqui](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict). Pode ser instalado pelo `pip` também.

Comment: Obrigado cara! Sou bem novato e estava sofrendo com isso aí. Já marquei como resposta!